# Is "K.K. Song" played in Club LOL?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I wanted to know whether or not K.K. Song can be played while DJ KK is doing his thing. I have stood around his preformances and not heard him play the song.

Comment: This is a late response, and whilst I have no way of giving solid proof (so not leaving an answer), I have heard him play K.K. Song whilst doing his DJ KK thing on week nights. He will also rarely use Totaka's Song (the theme K.K. Song is based on) as a transition piece (when going from town tune or gyroid segments back to his own music mixes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure in New Leaf, but in most Animal Crossing games, this is a secret song you have to request for him to play.

If there is a way to request a specific song from him, you will have to name it for him to play it for you.  Otherwise he will play one of his non-hidden tracks.

Comment: K.K. Song is *not* a secret song in Animal Crossing: New Leaf. It's actually a normal song that can come up randomly. Further, in New Leaf, while you can still do song requests from K.K. Slider on Saturday nights, DJ K.K. will play constantly in Club LOL after 8 PM on all other nights, selecting random songs from his playlist, or sometimes your town tune.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've seen it for myself, since I don't bother going to DJ K.K. performances. However, K.K. Song is *not* a hidden song in Animal Crossing: New Leaf, so...

**There's no reason why it wouldn't be.**

The songs DJ K.K. plays on non-Saturday nights are randomly selected from his [main playlist](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/kk-slider-songs) and your town tune. Presumably, this doesn't include the request-only songs, but since K.K. Song *isn't* one, it would be unusual if that particular song was left out of the list. Since no particular note has been made of this occurring, it seems safe to say that K.K. Song does not receive any special treatment.

Source: http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/club-lol#dj-kk-club-nights

Answer (score -1):

I just saw this happen and this question was one of the top Google results I got when I looked to confirm what I saw. I, too, have no proof, but DJ KK played KK Song during his routine with the album cover on the screen in the back. It surprised me to hear Totaka's song and I had to Google to see why DJ KK was playing it.